# How to properly set exit status in ZF2 console application?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use Zend\Console\Response::setErrorLevel  (http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Console.Response.html) to achieve this, but success (code 0) is set anyway.

And btw, Zend\Console\Response::send is marked as deprecated.

My app gets initialized, and I only call $app->run();

Is there anything else I should do in order to achieve this?

Thanks
v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so deprecation was the clue to the solution.

Instead of messing with response, we need to return ConsoleModel object, with error level properly set, from Action method and then it all makes sense.

Again :)

Comment: However, when i try to set the result message, and also provide the  error level, no output is shown in the console. Do you know how to solve this?